# Put a photo on the top right corner of a page

Tags: wrapfigure

I have the following code to show a picture around by some textes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{mickey}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I want to put the photo on (exact) top right of the page. So I want to remove the blank marge above the photo and on the right of the photo. Also I feel that the blank marge below the photo is too much.

Does anyone know how to amend the code?

[image]

Comment: Don't use the `center` environment. Instead, use `\centering`.

Comment: and what about controling the marge on the right hand side? I could control it by `\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}`, but is there a easy way to make sure that it is exactly right justified with the page?

Comment: Do you want the right and top of the photo to align with the text border or the page border?

Comment: Use `width=\linewidth`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Don't use the `center` environment. Use `\centering` instead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/5764).
2. To adjust the horizontal spacing, you need to adjust the length `\columnsep` (see section **2 Sizing and optional overhang** of the [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

If the vertical spacing at the bottom doesn't suit your needs, then you could use the [`adjustbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) to visually trim the content, or reduce the image's height from TeX's point of view:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[trim=0pt 12pt 0pt 0pt,width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, specify the number of rows to re-align

```
% # of rows -------|
%                  v
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{r}{4cm}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
```