# Adding a picture on the top right corner of a CV

Tags: graphics, cv

I have been trying for hours to customize a LaTeX code for a CV, by adding a picture on the top right corner of the page.

I have used `wrapfigure`, but it doesn't help. The text still overlaps the picture.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
{Fontin.otf}        
%%%

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%Tweak a bit the top margin
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

%Italian hyphenation for the word: ''corporations''
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

\begin{document}


\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command

%--------------------TITLE-------------
\par{\centering
    {\Huge Alessandro \textsc{Plasmati}
}\bigskip\par}

%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------
%Section: Personal Data
\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & Someplace, Italy  | dd Month 1912 \\
    \textsc{Address:}   & CV Inn 19, 20301, Milano, Italy \\
    \textsc{Phone:}     & +39 123 456789\\
    \textsc{email:}     & \href{mailto:alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com}            
{alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post the code as a part of your code, don't post links to external sites

Comment: Hi, sorry. I just did.

Comment: This question has been already asked and answered here.. Kindly look at the exchange here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230013/put-a-photo-on-the-top-right-corner-of-a-page

Comment: If the answer meets your request please accept it by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses the `fancyhdr` package to place a figure in the top right corner by defining a new page style.

The new style is applied  only to the first page.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\RequirePackage{xcolor, graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

%Italian hyphenation for the word: ''corporations''
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

%******************************************** added ,,,,,,,,,,,,
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\fancypagestyle{FIG}{% Define FIG as a new style
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}}
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% suppress the line
\fancyheadoffset[R]{2.5cm} %move the header to the right
%********************************************

\begin{document}        
    
    \thispagestyle{FIG} % apply FIG style only in this page <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<      

    %--------------------TITLE-------------
    \par{\centering
        {\Huge Alessandro \textsc{Plasmati}
        }\bigskip\par}
    
    %--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------
    %Section: Personal Data
    \section{Personal Data}
    
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
        \textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & Someplace, Italy  | dd Month 1912 \\
        \textsc{Address:}   & CV Inn 19, 20301, Milano, Italy \\
        \textsc{Phone:}     & +39 123 456789\\
        \textsc{email:}     & \href{mailto:alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com}            
        {alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com}
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```